# How can i set the inner text of an html element without it getting resized and also without affecting its overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I would like to know if it's possible to set the text content of an HTML element without it getting resized.

I am using Bootstrap and the card component. I want the to dynamically change the card text without affecting its overflow which I had set.

Sample html code

```html
<button onclick="setTxt('txt')" >set text</button>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div id="txt" style="height:50px;" class="card-text overflow-scroll">This is some text that is already within a card body.<div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some text i would like to put in the card-text

```
This is some text i want to put inside the card-text element
This is some text i want to put inside the card-text element
This is some text i want to put inside the card-text element
This is some text i want to put inside the card-text element
```

Here the javascript function that gets triggered by a button click event.

```js
function setTxt(elm){
document.getElementById(elm).textContent=mySampleText
}
```

I have tried other attributes that can set text of an element but all caused the element to resize and the text couldn't also scroll vertically like `innerHTML` and `innerText`

Comment: Whether this will change the element dimensions, has rather little to do with which exact method you use to get the text content changed, and more with what formatting you apply to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe . I thought the textContent property is a read-write string that contains the text content of an element and any descendant elements, including line breaks and it does not interpret HTML tags, so it wouldn't affect the size or overflow behavior of an element. Guess i was wrong

Comment: Why should the element dimensions _not_ change, when you change the amount of text in the element significantly? What _gave_ your initial element its dimensions in the first place - if not its content? (Yes, I see you got `style="height:50px;"`, so I am _assuming_ you are talking about the width here. Although that probably doesn't make too much sense either, when you are working within a Bootstrap grid? Not sure what exactly you want to achieve here to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe. Thanks, i tried formatting as you said and it worked

```js
function setTxt(elm){
document.getElementById(elm).textContent=mySampleText
  elm.style.height="60px"
  elm.style.overflow="scroll"
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem this solves. You already had height and scroll set.